# python: algorithm to filter almost same text

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing

I have a list of strings (topics on forum), like:

```
"[John Smith] Hello my friend 1080p"
"It was him! by Ronnie"
"new: Hello, my friend, J. Smith"
"Askade la bonko"
...
"Smith John: Hello my friend! (super mega must see!)"
"Alibaba won that game by John Smith"
```

I need to filter same content topic. 
From this list I can see that 1,3 (have comma in title) and pre-last (with ! in title) topics
have same content but a little bit different title ("Hello my friend").

Is there any algorithm to filter those?
I mean I want to have only one "Hello my friend" in my list of strings.
Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 3):

A commonly used model is the [bag of words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_words) model. A commonly used distance measure within this is [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

You have a list of content words. You probably want to include things like "Hello" and "friend", but not things like "by" and "and".

You probably also want to transform your input words, e.g. you probably don't want case to matter, and ideally you may want to strip off grammatical inflection. So you want something like this:

```
>>> content_words( "Smith John: Hello my friend (super mega must see!)" )
[ "smith", "john", "hello", "friend", "super", "mega", "must" ]
```

The other answer has good suggestions for how to do this.

Each subject line conceptually maps to a high-dimensional vector, with a dimension corresponding to each content word. There are two slight variations on the model (you can see which one works best on your data, if there's any significant difference):

- an element has 1 for its entry if the word appears and 0 if it does not
- the value of a vector at a dimension is the number of times the corresponding word appears

The cosine similarity of the two entries is the dot product of the vectors divided by product of the norm of the vectors.

As you can probably see you don't need to actually construct in memory those huge vectors (they're sparse -- most of the entries will be zero). Knowing the total number of content words as well as which of them appear in the relevant entries is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with [Stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) and [Lemmatisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation) .
There are a few powerful implementation in the text-processing framework [NTLK](http://nltk.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You are basically looking for similiarity of two sentences, pairwise. There are different methods of measuring the similiarity of two sentences.

With a [bag of words model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model), you can go and apply clustering algorithms like [k-Nearest-Neighbour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm), [k-Means](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Means-Algorithmus), etc.

I hope this can give you some inspiration